# Replaced my first power cord. Will I set the house on fire?

Tags: 240v

I’ve replaced the power cord of an appliance for the very first time. How does it look? I have switched the appliance on for 3 mins and there were no fires. I just want to make sure it’s safe. It’s a NEMA 6-20P plug.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great question and it's good that you included pics. Technically, you should tighten the screws to the recommended torque setting using a torque screwdriver. I'll bet you didn't! (Sadly, most electricians don't either.) It looks like there should be a ground wire attached to that 4th screw hiding in the back. Are all the little pieces of wire from you trimming the stripped ends to length or did they fall off at some other time? _Why_ did you replace the cord - was the original damaged? What kind of appliance? Please [edit] to add a pic of the labeling on the new cord.

Comment: @FreeMan -- they swapped the cord because it's an European appliance that had a Schuko plug on it, and they were converting it to NEMA 6 for US use

Comment: Did your chord have ring connectors crimped  to it originally?

Comment: @FreeMan - I replaced the cord because the appliance is European and I have now moved to the US.
ThreePhaseEel - this is the right understanding
JACK - the original cord it did not have the ring connectors.

Comment: All those twisted strands on the ground ... did they spall off the wires as you attached them to the screws?  That is to say, are there fewer strands around the screws than are in the wires?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - yes, the twisted strands came from the wire as I was attaching them to the screws. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, it is.  You may need to sacrifice a little bit of cord length to have a few "gos" at learning to shape the stranded wires properly so they don't do that.

Comment: Yeah, copper is soft and kinks easily. You really want the full battery of strands to remain through the connection. I'd re-strip a little more than necessary, twist gently by hand until snug, then clip off the extra length with a sharp wire cutter. That said, I've seen far worse in service for far longer without catastrophe.

Answer (score 2):

we don’t really know but if you have turned it on and it works without arcs and sparks. Then if you touch it you don’t get shocked you probably did a good job.  Well now I see the first photo of the connections it looks a little short on the wrap around the screws I think the code book has an example of 66-75% wrap NEC exhibit 110.3 its for aluminum wire but copper should follow the same rules 2/3-3/4 wrap. I would not be afraid of using this but might try to get the wires a bit tighter around the screws but good first job.

You left the normal electricians mess according to my wife , When I was an apprentice my training supervisor said don’t wast your high dollar time picking up wire that’s for the clean up guy. But I try depending on the job,

Note I find with stranded wire a pre twist of counter clockwise helps keep it tighter.